# How to style different li's

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to add different styles to different li's and the result should be something like this

```
test one  | test two | test three
```

```css
#nav ul,
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

#nav ul li {
  float: left;
  height: 45px;
  padding: 8px;
  width: 100px;
}

#nav ul li .border {
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}

#nav ul li a {
  color: red;
  font-size: 15px;
}

#nav ul li a:hover {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">

  <ul>
    <li>test one</li>
    <li class="border">test two</li>
    <li class="border">test three</li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Hello in what sense you are asking to style the li's, i mean using images, color, or diff css on different li,s? There are so many ways to accomplish this....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

write like this:

```
li + li{
 border-left:1px solid #ccc;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/fpQ8y/

```css
#nav ul,
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

#nav ul li {
  float: left;
  height: 45px;
  padding: 8px;
  width: 100px;
}

#nav ul li+li {
  border-left: 1px solid red;
}

#nav ul li a {
  color: red;
  font-size: 15px;
}

#nav ul li a:hover {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">

  <ul>
    <li>test one</li>
    <li class="border">test two</li>
    <li class="border">test three</li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: lol :O this is working but how. I mean i never seen such a thing

Comment: It's a adjacent-selectors. Check this for more http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors

Answer (score 1):

You can add a left border to all li's & remove it from first.

```
#nav ul li {
float:left;
height:45px;
padding:8px;
width:100px;
border-left:1px solid #cb2326;
}

#nav ul li:first-child {border:none;}
```

check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Squeg/

Answer (score 0):

so just use id's instead of a class to select each list item individually and apply the styles that you want. you will have to repeat some of your code for each li.

```
   <li id="li1">test one</li>
   <li id="li2">test two</li>
   <li id="li3">test three</li>

CSS

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
#li1 {
    border-left:1px solid #ccc;
    float:left;
    height:45px;
    padding:8px;
    width:100px;
}
#li1 a {
    color:red;
    font-size:15px;
}
#li1 a:hover {
    color:blue;
}
```

and repeat that for the rest of the id's changing whatever you want for each individual item.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can get results through first & last child property for example see the link :-
http://jsfiddle.net/nFfzy/

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do.

[The Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aniketpant/VMt6P/)

This is the better method which uses CSS3 `:first-of-type` and `:nth-of-type` properties.

```css
nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

nav ul li {
  float: left;
  height: 45px;
  padding: 8px;
  width: 100px;
}

nav ul li:first-of-type {
  border-right: 2px solid #ff4500;
}

nav ul li:nth-of-type(2n) {
  border-right: 2px solid #ff0450;
}

nav ul li a {
  color: #222;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #ff0450;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href=#>test one</a></li>
    <li><a href=#>test two</a></li>
    <li><a href=#>test three</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

One more solution,
Just change this css:

```
#nav ul li .border {
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

By this:

```
#nav ul li:nth-child(2) {
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```